# CLI with Application dispatching

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have added application dispatching for the app I am building in Flask so I can support several configurations (same app, different config). I am doing a variation of [Dispatch by Path](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appdispatch/#dispatch-by-path).

The app uses the Flask CLI. How can I integrate the CLI with the application dispatcher? For example, executing `flask app1` executes
the `flask` command of the `app1` behind the dispatcher.

Is there a way for flask to allow or help with something like this? Or any recommendation? I did not find anything in the docs. I am using the latest version of Flask with Python 3.

Thanks in advance.